# Quickly finding the last item in a database Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I just inherited some cakePHP code and I am not very familiar with it (or any other php/serverside language).  I need to set the id of the item I am adding to the database to be the value of the last item plus one, originally I did a call like this:

```
$id = $this->Project->find('count') + 1;
```

but this seems to add about 8 seconds to my page loading (which seems weird because the database only has about 400 items) but that is another problem.  For now I need a faster way to find the id of the last item in the database, is there a way using find to quickly retrieve the last item in a given table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a very bad approach on setting the id.

You do know that, for example, MySQL supports auto-increment for INT-fields and therefore will set the id automatically for you?

The suggested functions `getLastInsertId` and `getInsertId` will only work after an insert and not always.

I also can't understand that your call adds 8 seconds to your siteload. If I do such a call on my table (which also has around 400 records) the call itself only needs a few milliseconds. There is no delay the user would notice.

I think there might be a problem with your database-setup as this seems very unlikely.

Also please have a look if your database supports auto-increment (I can't imagine that's not possible) as this would be the easiest way of adding your wanted functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I got the autoincrement to work and then I was able to retrieve the id with a call to getLastInsertID after adding the data to the model!

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
$id = $this->Project->getLastInsertID();
$id++;
```

The method can be found in cake/libs/model/model.php in line 2768

As well as on [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979709/getlastinsertid-in-cakephp)

Cheers!

Comment: I tried that, but $this->Project->getLastInsertID();  always returns 0

Comment: what about $this->Project->getInsertID();?  It's very similar. Also, what version of cakephp are you running? 1.2? 1.3?

Comment: $this->Project->getInsertID(); also seems to return 0, I'm using 1.2.8.

Comment: maybe you could go for something along these lines instead?  it's not as elegant but it is a solution.

`$lastItem = $this->Project->find('first', array('order' => array('Project.created DESC')));`

Comment: Sadly that seems as slow as count.  Maybe the real question I need to ask is why getLastInsterID always returns 0.

Comment: It returns 0 because there was no insert.

Comment: @dhofstet - You make a good point, as did @Tim in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the cakePHP3 solution to this you simply use last().

ie:

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
....
$myrecordstable=Tableregistry::get('Myrecords');
$myrecords=$myrecordstable->find()->last();
$lastId = $myrecords->id;
....
```