# get user id of just registered user in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

How can i retrieve the user id of a user who has recently register.. in CakePHP 2.1 ie

right now, user with name `poo` entered some registeration credentials
like `username` and `password` and

database structure is below

### users

```
id  Auto_Increment
username
password
```

now, once the user is created , i want to display a message to user as

**You have registered successfully and you id is xxx**
these xxx are integer number

---

Code for register.ctp view

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('label'=>'First Name'));
echo $this->Form->end('Register');
```

---

Code for controller

```
 public function register(){
            if ($this->request->is('post')){

                if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){

                   // $this->Session->setFlash('User is created' . $this->YourModel->id);
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__('You have registered successfully and your ID is %s', $this->YourModel->id));
                    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
                } else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Cannot register a user');
                }

            }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the corresponding action in your controller (probably UserController::add())?

Comment: @pixelistik add some more information on it.

Comment: this might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020439/1239506

Comment: @MoyedAnsari I believe, the below answer by nappo is good rather getting last id from database.. If you think, `more than 3 persons` then we may get some problem while retrieving and the same time.

Comment: @Rafee I agree, i just show all the possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a model's save()-function is called, the just added ID is available through the attribute

`$this->YourModel->id;`

You can pass the ID to the view or just create a flash message:

```
$this->Session->setFlash(__('You have registered successfully and your ID is %s', $this->YourModel->id));`
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-save-array-data-null-boolean-validate-true-array-fieldlist-array