# How to get last id in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using query in cakephp

```
$this->Menu->query("INSERT INTO frd_menus SET menuName= '".$_REQUEST['menuname']."'");
```

How to get last insert id of this query in cakephp? Please advice.

Comment: what frd_menus is? Is it somehow related to menus table?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/11020439/1239506

Comment: You should [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187920/3197383) because the most upvoted answer is a wrong solution and may cause bugs in your application. To accept my answer, check the check symbol on the left of my answer.

Answer (score 19):

If there is no specific reason.

You should use

```
$this->Menu->save($data)
```

to insert the data. 
Then you can use

```
$this->Menu->getLastInsertId();
```

to get the last inserted id.

Comment: YES! I dont understand why there are so many people using "Model::query()" instead of regular Model methods such as save, saveAssociated, etc.

Comment: $this->Menu->id contains the id as well, straight after the save, without needing to do another trip to the database.

Comment: This method shoudn't be use for this use case, please read the CAUTION section of my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187920/3197383 to understand why.

Answer (score 12):

In almost cases you should use the model method to query your database.

`Model::query()` exists to run complex queries that will be more complex than using the model methods, or in a few cases when you have not the choice.

In your case this is very useful because `Model::save()` runs a callback in the framework that set the `Model::id` attribute for you.

So, this permit you to get it back immediately:

```
if ($this->Menu->save($data)) {
   $lastId = $this->Menu->id;
}
```

> ## BE CAUTION !
>
> On the other side and like said by other responses there is the following method:
>
> ```
> Model::getLastInsertId()
> ```
>
> But **YOU MUST BE VERY CAREFUL with this method** and **YOU SHOULD'NT USE IT IN THIS USE CASE** because it get the **LAST** inserted, but **NOT the last you just inserted in the previous code statement!**
>
> If a user (during another concurrent request on the server) save data between `save()` and `getLastInsertId()`, **it will return that of this second user!**
>
> THUS, the following answers are **BAD** answers **for this use case**:
>
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20701165/3197383
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700561/3197383
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24059193/3197383
> - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29874758/3197383

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->Menu->getLastInsertId();
```

you can get the last insert ID by this

Comment: Hi Manish, Thanks for the answer but is not showing the last insert. It works only save() function.

Comment: Then use for find->first() with order: id=>DESC

Comment: Using Model::find('first') would also not be an acceptable solution - you can never guarantee that someone else hasn't saved a record after yours in the time before you make the find call. 
Example: Thousands of people using the app at the same time and two people perform the same action in close proximity may result in retrieving the wrong ID; This could be catastrophic depending on the situation

Comment: This method shoudn't be use for this use case, please read the CAUTION section of my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187920/3197383 to understand why.

Answer (score 4):

use orderby desc option in cakephp.

```
$lastCreated = $this->Menu->find('first', array('order' => array('Menu.filedname' =>'desc'))`);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try :

```
$data = array('menuName' => $_REQUEST['menuname'])
$this->Menu->create();
$this->Menu->save($data);
$id = $this->Menu->getLastInsertId();
```

Comment: This method shoudn't be use for this use case, please read the CAUTION section of my response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24187920/3197383 to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->Menu->query("INSERT INTO frd_menus SET menuName= '".$_REQUEST['menuname']."'");
$result = $this->Menu->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
$last_id = $result[0][0];
```

this should works, but I think it will be better if you create a relationship between `menus` and `frd_menus` and use `save` function

Comment: One should also note that this an SQL injection vulnerability! Never ever inject user input into queries like that, always use `DboSource::value()` for data inserted into [`Model::query()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query)! `$name = $this->Menu->getDataSource()->value($_REQUEST['menuname']); $this->Menu->query("INSERT INTO frd_menus SET menuName=" . $name);` ps. you are missing a closing parenthese/semicolon.

Comment: Downvoted for SQL injection and overall this is just wrong. If that's code from a CakePHP app I wonder why you use Cake at all.

Comment: WHY? WHY? WHY DO YOU USE PLAIN SQL? Please TELL ME WHY!? Furthermore, "$_REQUEST"? like @burzum said, I don't understand why/how you are using CakePHP.

Comment: It's not me, I just copied user code. I don't know wy @Jaiprakash Singh uses plain sql, but maybe he has his reason.

Comment: So, if you see an user writing horrible code then you wouldn't fix it but make it worse?

Answer (score 2):

Very easy. Just do it.

```
$this->Menu->save($newMenu);
$menuId = $this->Menu->id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$this->ModelName->save($this->request->data);
$insertedId = $this->ModelName->id;
```

Answer (score 0):

In **CakePHP 3.x** you can do it like:

```
$data = $this->model->save($data);
$data->id; // this will give the inserted id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$this->Menu->id; // For User Model
```

You can also use Model function but below code will return last inserted id of model with given model name for this example it will return Menu model data

```
$this->Menu->getLastInsertId();
$this->Menu->getInsertID();
```

Answer (score -1):

Below are the options:

```
echo $this->Registration->id;
```

OR

```
echo $this->Registration->getInsertID();
```

OR

```
echo $this->Registration->getLastInsertId();
```

Here, you can replace Registration with your model name.

**Note:** This function doesn't work if you run the insert query manually

Thanks