# Autoincrement per user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have a table with invoices. Each invoice belongs to a user.

So the table table has `id`, `user_id` columns.

I want a third column, for example invoice_id that is autoincrement based on the user.

So for example **user 1** will have invoices with `id 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...` And **user 2** will also have invoices with `id 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...`

I know I can make a function that checks the last value for a specific user and assign the next but is there no other "easier" more proper way to do this with `cakephp` or `mysql`?

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979709/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getlastinsertid-in-cakephp

Comment: Depending on the database engine you're using, you might be able to take avantage of a composite primary key with autoincrement - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html - though I believe this is only available with MyISAM and BDB engines for MySQL.... You don't specify which database you're using, so I'm guessing MySQL

Comment: I saw this method as well, but I prefer to not use a method that is specific for only MyISAM

Comment: There is no reason whatsoever, except aesthetic one, where you want to have "nice" sequential numbering *based on user*. However, since people are people and we often like useless things - you perform this using AFTER INSERT triggers on the invoice table. As for how, there are tons of examples on how to use MySQL triggers. However, believe me when I talk from experience - you don't need nor want that.

Comment: Well, it is needed, because each user can view their invoice and invoice id. And I do not want the user to see ids like 1,4, 9,16..

Comment: There you go, there's no use except aesthetic one. Whether the ID is 1 or 1021031231 is absolutely irrelevant - it's a number, it works the same in the end except you *think* that it looks nicer to the user. Implementing this **safely** is a completely another thing and since you have virtually no gains and you impose faults (it's actually not that simple to implement it safely as you might think at first, I learned the hard way).

Answer (score 0):

you have to do it in a `beforeSave` callback in your `Invoice` Model

something like:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array())
{

    if(!$this->id)
    {
        $user_id = $this->data['Invoice']['user_id'];
        $invoice = $this->find(
            'first', 
            array
            (
                'fields' => array('MAX(invoice_id) AS invoice_id'),
                'conditions' => array('Invoice.user_id' => $user_id )
            )
        );
        $invoice_id = $invoice [0]['invoice_id'] + 1 ;


        $this->data['Invoice']['invoice_id'] = $invoice_id ;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above code should work. Anyway somehow I'm not sure this is the best way to achieve that, so keep lookink for other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

In your Schema add

```
$t->addColumn('id', [
    'type' => 'integer',
    'autoIncrement' => true,
])
```

Comment: This won't work since user 1 will for example have invoice 1,2,4,8 and user 2 will have 3,5,6,7..