# last generate id manual query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have apply manual query in cakephp and not get last generate id

My query is this

```
$areas = $this->Area->query("insert into  areas (Area_ID,Parent_Area_ID,Area) values ('','".$Parent_Area_ID."','".$Area_name."')");
```

How i get last id ?

Comment: I'm smelling SQL injection vulnerabilities... ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Comment: Why are you not using a model as wrapper for this? This would make it so much cleaner and easier to work with...

Comment: It seems highly likely that `Area_ID` is the primary key - in which case you're using query for no benefit and at the cost of exposing yourself to SQL injection and losing Cake's default ORM functions - why aren't you calling save on a model? If you're using CakePHP, _use_ CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$this->Area->getInsertID();
```

More detail here:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getinsertid

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo $this->Area->getLastInsertID();
```

If this doesn't work check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979709/what-is-the-equivalent-to-getlastinsertid-in-cakephp#answer-3632155) from a similar question